# What is the mean and variance of $1/X$ if $X$ is skew normal distributed?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, variance, means

The density function of [skew normally distributed random variable $X$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) is given as

$$f(x)=\frac{2}{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(\alpha \left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)$$
where $\phi$ is standard Gaussian density, $\Phi$ is standard Gaussian cumulative distribution function with location $\mu$, scale $\sigma$ and shape $\alpha$ parameters.

> What is the mean and variance of the random variable $Y=1/X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moments of the form $\mathsf EX^{-n}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ do not exist for the skew normal distribution because this distribution has positive density in a neighborhood of the origin.  If, however, you define $\mathsf EX^{-1}$ in the sense of the Cauchy Principal Value
$$
\mathsf EX^{-1}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\Bbb R\setminus(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}\frac{f_X(x)}{x}\,\mathrm dx,
$$
then an explicit expression is given by [Peng (2008)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167715208000382) in the form
$$
\mathsf EX^{-1}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sigma}\mathcal D\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt 2\sigma}\right)-\frac{2\sqrt 2\alpha}{\sigma\sqrt\pi}\Bbb D\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt 2\sigma},\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\log(\alpha+\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}),
$$
where
$$
\mathcal D(z)=\exp(-z^2)\int_0^z\exp(t^2)\,\mathrm dt
$$
is the Dawson function and
$$
\Bbb D(x,a)=\exp(-x^2)\int_0^x\exp(t^2)\mathcal D(at)\,\mathrm dt.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is skew normal, then $Y = 1/X$ does not possess a first moment. Thus mean and variance are not defined.

Comment: This is what Mathematica told me. I am wondering still something useful such as the mode of the density of Y. Is it possible? and the corresponding variance using mode as the mean.

Comment: It is certainly possible to say something about the median of $Y$. You should write a new post with your questions.

Comment: To say something analytically or just in terms of equation solving?

Comment: Continue as chat?

Comment: yes sure. how to do it?

Comment: Click on the "Chat" link in the bottom left corner of this page and then look for the SkewNormal chat room which I just created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117109/discussion-between-hans-engler-and-seyhmus-gungoren).